# Fomatting Windows Path To Be Used As An Argument

Tags: python-3.x

A bit new to Python (and to stackoverflow), so please bear with me.  :)

Here's my code problem.

```
import os

X = input("Enter Path to Windows directory: ")

path = "r'" + X + "'"

do_it = os.listdir(path)

print (do_it)
```

Yields the error message.

```
Enter Path to Windows directory?

C:\Users\someone\Desktop

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-93c73304f480> in <module>
      3 X = input("Enter Path to Windows directory?")
      4 path = "r\"" + X + "\""
----> 5 Y = os.listdir(path)
      6 print (Y)
      7 

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:     'r"C:\\Users\\someone\\Desktop"'
```

So the path variable needs to be correctly formatted prior to being used at os.listdir as an argument.

I tried something like.

```
Y = re.sub("\", "\\", path)
```

But that didn't work, and it looks like it might be a bad idea anyway for some reason.

Is there a way to format the path variable to be used as an acceptable argument?

Comment: try printing path before passing to os.listdir to see what is the value

Comment: @SreeramTP the value is in the error `'r"C:\\Users\\someone\\Desktop"'` that is wrong. Replace the line `path = "r'" + X + "'"` with `path =  X`

Comment: I've just tried this (on Win) and this `path = "r'" + X + "'"` is not needed. Python is smart enough to auto-escape the backslash path separators.  Try just plugging `X` into `os.listdir(X)`. Or, just enter the path as: `c:/users/username/Desktop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is smart enough to use the correct path separator, or to auto-escape the backslash in a Win file path.

Therefore this will work:

```
x = input('Path: ')
>>> c:\users\username\desktop

>>> os.listdir(x)
```

Or, just use a forward-slash as the path separator:

```
x = input('Path: ')
>>> c:/users/username/desktop

>>> os.listdir(x)
```

Output:

```
['file1', 'file2', 'file3', ... ]
```

Comment: @Will - Thank you for posting a complete question, enabling us to help straight away. (Question unvoted).  All the best in your Python adventures mate.